# Как устанавливать расположение Button процентно в constraintLayout относительно размера экрана?

Tags: android

Я знаю как установить ширину и высоту компонента процентно:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.7"
```

Мне нужно расположить Button относительно размер экрана. Скажите пожалуйста какой атрибут за это отвечает?! Спасибо!

Comment: для позиционирования на экране в процентах [можно использовать Guideline](https://constraintlayout.com/layouts/percentlayout.html). Определив опорную линию к ней привязывается виджет. Так же можно использовать параметр bias виджета для смещения относительно центра, но это работает только с параметром match_constraint, что не всегда можно использовать

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/voteCount"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_text"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.7"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

Вы забыли добавить параметры layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf и app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf которые привязывают вашу кнопку к родительским сторонам.

Comment: Я не про это. Я знаю что можно привязывать. Я про адаптивное расположение. Ну или резиновое

Comment: @mr.hinkal05 это адаптивное расположение